# EnvironementVariable not correct in AzureDevops pipe-line

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

My customer has an onprem AzureDevops set-up.
I have a dedicated windows server that I use as build server. The agent is installed an runs as user X.

The java application is build using custom scripts created by a 3th party. The build is launched using this script in the YAML :

```
cmd /c ""C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i --
 ./deployment/buildKit.sh -kn $(buildnumber) -ah /C/apache-ant-1.10.9""
```

It all worked fine until we had to change the java version. When logged on with user X interactively on the build server, I installed the new java-version to use, changed JAVA_HOMe,  the build script runs fine with no errors using the newly required java version.

If I run SET on the machine as user X I get :

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6+10
```

I added SET in the YAML to see which JAVA_HOME is used and in the log I get :

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.275.1-hotspot\
```

Which is the 'old' version. Hence the build fails.
Any Ideas why running the pipeline has a different JAVA_HOME compared to interactif ? And how to solve it ?

Comment: have you tried restarting the build-agent or maschine ? the agent only reads these variables on startup so if you update a program like java and update the environment-variables the agent will still work the old values

Comment: OMG such a newbie mistake !!!! That did the trick. Thx.

Comment: @D.J. Can you covert your comment into reply so Bril can mark it as answer?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build-agent only reads environment variables on startup of the agent. If you update/install a programm while the agent is running the agent will not know that environment variables have been updated and passes the old values through down to the build processes.

After any update or installation of a program or SDK on a build maschine you should  ***restart the build agent*** so it will re-read the updated environment variables.